# 100% width div with padding showing horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS Code:

```
.topBar {
    width:100%; 
    height:70px;
    position:absolute;
    /*position:fixed;
    z-index:999;*/
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    padding:10px;
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    border-bottom:2px solid #F36F25;
}
```

but because it is 100% wide and has a 10px padding it shows a horizontal scroll bar.

how can i stop this from happening but keep the padding and 100% width?

I have tried:

```
overflow-x: none;
```

in my css but i still want the horizontal scrollbar to show when the screen gets too small

Comment: did you find a solution to your issue? did my answer help?

Answer (score 12):

Basically the `div.topBar` is 100% + 10px (x2). So it's actually more than 100% (hence the scroll box). The general way to do this is the add another `div` inside the parent `div` and add the `padding:10px` to that. Another way is to use `box-sizing:border-box` which actually honours the 100% rule!

Take a look at this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/UVKuA/).

Comment: @user3424754 ... and another method appears! The red-box example is the best cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `box-sizing` CSS property. Add this to `.topBar` : `box-sizing:border-box;`

```css
.topBar {
    width:100%; 
    height:70px;
    position:absolute;
    /*position:fixed;
    z-index:999;*/
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    padding:10px;
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    border-bottom:2px solid #F36F25;
    
    box-sizing:border-box; /** <- Add this **/
}
```

```html
<div class="topBar"></div>
```

This property includes padding (and borders if you have some) in the width you set to the element. so if you set `width: 100%;` it won't overflow the parent container anymore.

[More info about box-sizing on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)